# Cast object[] to Type[] when array elements are same Type

Tags: c#

I am parsing arbritrary structures (JSON) and returning them as `object`.

```cs
var structure = ParseStructure();   // returns object
```

In some situations, when these structures are arrays, the array elements can all have the same type.

I don't know what these Types will be at compile time, only at runtime.

Rather than `ParseStructure` returning an `object`, which is actually an `object[]`, which is actually a `MyType[]` - how can I create a new array that is of the most specific type that they all elements share?

```cs
object ParseStructure()
{
    return new object[] { new Item(0), new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3) };  // Fake Code
}

...

object value = ParseStructure();
object returnValue = SimplifyType(value);    // returns Item[]
return returnValue;
```

How do I implement SimplifyType?

```cs
object SimplifyType(object value)
{
  // what goes here?
}
```

**Note:** in some situations, `object` will be the common type ancestor, and we won't be able to make the type any more specific.

```cs
object ParseStructure()
{
    return new object[]{ 0, "one", 2.0, new Number(3) };  // Fake Code
}

...
var value = ParseStructure();
var returnValue = SimplifyType(value);    // returns object[]
```

Comment: What good will this do? `simplifyObject` will still just return object because you dont know what type it will be. JSON parsers exist for a reason!

Comment: In the simple case where it is just an array of objects, in order to cast the `object` to `Item[]` I would need to do `((object[])value).Select(x => (Item)x).ToArray()`

I really want to be able to do a single cast i.e. `(Item[])value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type that json should be parsed to:

```
T[] GetJson<T>(string jsonStr)
{
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(jsonStr);
}
```

now you can use it like:

```
 var result = GetJson<MyType>(jsonStr);
```

Comment: @Jamiec No problem sir

Comment: The issue with this option is that I don't know what T is at compile time.
Ah! I took that detail out of the question before I posted, apologies!